# Useless boxing with generic types

Tags: c#, cil, boxing

The `TestMethod` of this sample code

```
public class Test<T> where T : class
{
    public void TestMethod(T param)
    {
        PrivateMethod(param);
    }

    private void PrivateMethod(object obj)
    {

    }
}
```

compiles into this IL code:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldarg.1
IL_0002:  box        !T
IL_0007:  call       instance void class SensorPositioner2.Test`1<!T>::PrivateMethod(object)
IL_000c:  ret
```

As I see the `box` instruction, would a new object be created during the `TestMethod` call?

If so, how can I avoid this? If not, why `box` is needed here?

Comment: A new object would not be created for a reference type, because it will be optimised away by the Jitter (see the dupe for details).

Comment: @MatthewWatson, sorry, I can't understand where to get the details. May you clarify this, probably as an answer.

Comment: Click the link at the top of your question underneath where it says "This question already has answers here".

Answer (score 2):

The boxing is required because of the `object` parameter in the `PrivateMethod()`. You could change the signature of PrivateMethod to use Generic Type instead of object to avoid boxing.

```
private void PrivateMethod(T obj)
{

}
```

This would translate to

```
 
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldarg.1     
IL_0003:  call        UserQuery+Test<>.PrivateMethod  // Your method
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ret
```

Comment: No, I can't. PrivateMethod simulates an API method with an object parameter. That's the point of the question.